# shell script, for loop, does loop wait for execution of the command to iterate

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, exec

I have a shell script with a for loop. Does loop wait for execution of the command in its body before iterating?

Thanks in Advance

Here is my code. Will the commands execute sequentially or parallel?

```
for m in "${mode[@]}" 
    do 
        cmd="exec $perlExecutablePath $perlScriptFilePath --owner $j -rel $i -m $m"
        $cmd
        eval "$cmd"
    done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't background-ed the command, then yes.

For example:

```
for i in {1..10}; do cmd; done
```

waits for `cmd` to complete before continuing the loop, whereas:

```
for i in {1..10}; do cmd &; done
```

doesn't.

If you want to run your commands in parallel, I would suggest changing your loop to something like this:

```
for m in "${mode[@]}" 
do 
    "$perlExecutablePath" "$perlScriptFilePath" --owner "$j" -rel "$i" -m "$m" &
done
```

This runs each command in the background, so it doesn't wait for one command to finish before the next one starts.

An alternative would be to look at [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your great efforts

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel $perlExecutablePath $perlScriptFilePath --owner $j -rel $i -m {} ::: "${mode[@]}"
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel